# Puppet agent very slow runs with large LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, puppet, winbinder

I have a puppet master that is on a server that uses winbind connected to a Universities large LDAP / active directory. When winbind is on the puppet runs are extremely slow and when winbind is turned off the puppet runs are normal.

I believe that puppet might be looping through every user in active directory or something similar but I'm unsure. It's not an option for me to turn of winbind so I have been just dealing with the long puppet runs and haven't found a solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could not the master run on a VM that needs no LDAP connection?

Comment: Thats what I have been considering. Moving puppet master to a separate machine. Question is then, is it only puppet master that needs to use NSS, or is it just puppet runs in general?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/aV0KBN_0kgA), an active LDAP client configuration on the master host does indeed incur a performance penalty, and an apparent solution is to reconfigure in `nsswitch.conf`. If that is not an option, a supposed mitigation strategy is a caching `nscd`.